# 2D-metric to diagonal form with determinant 1

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I wonder whether it is always possible to bring a 2D Riemannian metric to a diagonal form with determinant one by changing the coordinates, i.e. for the line element
$$
    ds^2 = A(x,y)\, dx^2 + B(x,y)\, dy^2
$$
to obtain $A(x,y)\, B(x,y) = 1$ everywhere.

It is known that one can bring the metric to a diagonal and conformally flat form
$$
  ds^2 = C(x,y)\, (dx^2 + dy^2)
$$
but it is not enough yet.

Comment: @ Nikodem your metric is diagonal , the condition that the  determinate  of  the metric equal one  is: $B(x,y)=\frac{1}{A(x,y)}$   for arbitrary A(x,y)

Comment: Yes, but this is exactly the question: can I fulfill this condition by changing coordinates? In general the functions $A(x,y)$ and $B(x,y)$ are unrelated to each other.

Comment: Crossposted to https://mathoverflow.net/q/393990/13917

Comment: I’m voting to close this question partly because it was crossposted.

Comment: It was crossposted at mathoverflow as I didn't know who will be motivated to help me answer it. But it is not off-topic! I'm really disappointed with "This question does not appear to be about physics". It comes directly from a physical problem I am working on -- the Dirac equation in curved 2D-space.